# How to fix package signature doesn't match

Tags: google-play-services

I got this error while trying to install google play services on my Huawei device using googlifier . I did this before and it worked well but after i lost gms by mistake i had to get GMS again in the same way and everything was successful except microg - Huawei fix couldn't installed showing me error (package signature does not match the installed app)even if i tried to find the microg app in app list in the setting and in the file manager android. Please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.